# Destroy an Intent?

Tags: android

When I create a Intent:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, myclass.class);
this.startActivity(in);
```

I create a new Intent but the last Intent is not destroy
It's still in memory
How can I kill this last destroy?

So I want to create two Intents in two different classes:
in the first class I write this:

```
Intent in1 = new Intent(this, myclass2.class);
this.startActivity(in);
```

and in second class I write this:

```
Intent in2 = new Intent(this, myclass1.class);
this.startActivity(in2);
```

but when I Click in1 will create and the in2 will destroy, and when i Click on in2 the in2 will create and in1 will destroy.

a want to clean my phone memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent the user from going on to the previous `Activity` by overriding the back key functionality like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
       //doing nothing on pressing Back key
       return;
    }
```

Though this approach is not encouraged.And as everybody knows, the `Activity` will be automatically killed when certain aspects come up like memory requirement. You cannot destroy one `Activity` at your free will.

Though for specific cases like a welcome splash screen maybe, you can do one of the following two things:

1) call `finish()` method on your current `Activity` as you move onto
   your new `Activity`(generally done when using `Thread`).

2) use the following in your `manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".WelcomeScreen" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

This will tell the device to not keep this `Activity` on the `Activity` stack.

Comment: yeaaaah thank's man :D
nohistory="true" in the xml file and new intent in my class :D so cool thank's again

Answer (score 2):

Activities remain in memory until Android decides it should be removed.  Don't worry about it.  It'll get destroyed when more memory is needed.  It's effectively "unused" memory until your top activity uses it.

Comment: yes, but when i click on back boutton of emulator i get the last information and i don't want this :/

Comment: It sounds like you're passing in the same intent object from the last use.  If you back out of an Activity then restart it with a new intent, it should act as a new Activity.  Null out the previous intent and create a new one.  Call startActivity() with the new intent and it should act as if it was restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question...
You want to start a new activity and destroy the previous one?
If this is what you need, you can use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, myActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

The "CLEAR_TOP" flag tell "Hey! I want to start this activity and kill all the other ones!"

Comment: Yes, I want destroy the previous Intent so i past your code but when i Click on back button of the emulator(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)... I have not a message error and the previous information still on the Intent :( 

can i clean the layout ? or destroy the Intent

Answer (score 0):

Since the Android runtime environment uses garbage collection (just like "traditional" Java), you won't need to worry about manually destroying objects in most cases. The memory taken up by the unused `Intent` object will be recycled if the system needs additional space for new objects.